# Comparing 2 dates using following format yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, date

I need to compare two dates along with time portion.

I need to check it upto hh:mm:ss only.

Can any one suggest any util i can use for it or any suggestion for doing programatically.

Thanks,

Narendra

Comment: "compare" == before/after OR date-difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse your dates into `Date` objects, then use `getTime` to do the comparison. `Date` also implements `Comparable` so you can use that directly if you prefer.

Comment: how to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

To compare just the date portion, the simplest thing to do is

```
 int cmp = date1.substring(0, 10).compareTo(date2.substring(0,10));
```

You don't need to convert them into a true date object as the strings will be in the same order. This is like @rodion's answer except his will compare the time as well.

If performance IS important to you I suggest you leave the strings as strings, converting them to a date object is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string comparison like: `"2010:01:01 00:00:01".compareTo("2010:01:01 00:00:02")`. This will return -1, 0 or 1 for when the first date is before, same or after the second date respectively

If you have the `Date` or `Calendar` object available you can compare dates using `Calendar.before(date)` and `Calendar.after(date)` methods, but this will take into account milliseconds so you have to be careful to reset milliseconds to 0 before comparing.

If performance is not so important to you I would suggest string comparison above.

Comment: String comparison works, because the format has a fixed number of digits for each part (year, month, day, ...) and has them ordered from higher to lower values.

Comment: @Narendra: sorry, I thought you meant up to and including hh:mm:ss. Use @Peter Lawrey's answer for your needs.